# How to write the data of 3 dictionaries in a table separated by tab into a text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

Say I have the following 3 dictionaries:

```
d1 = {'Ben': {'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'false'}, 'Tom': {'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'true'}}
d2 = {'Ben': {'Strength': 'wo_mana', 'Int': 'wi_mana', 'Speed': 'wo_mana'}, 'Tom': {'Int': 'wi_mana', 'Agility': 'wo_mana'}}
d3 = {'Ben': {'Strength': '1.10', 'Int': '1.20', 'Speed': '1.50'}, 'Tom': {'Int': '1.40', 'Agility': '1.60'}}
```

I want to write the data of the 3 dictionaries above into a table separated by tab into a .txt or .csv file using `with open('filename', 'w') as f:`

My desired output (when opened in Excel):

```
Name Skill Magic wo_mana          wi_mana
Ben  true  false Strength = 1.10  Int = 1.20
                 Speed = 1.50
Tom  true  true  Agility = 1.60   Int = 1.40
```

My code so far:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w')as f:
  f.write("Name\tSkill\tMagic\two_mana\twi_mana\n")
  for key in d1:
    f.write('%s\t%s\t%s\n' %(key, d1[key]['Skill'], d1[key]['Magic']))
```

and I got this:

```
Name Skill Magic wo_mana wi_mana
Ben  true  false
Tom  true  true
```

How am I supposed to write the `wo_mana` and `wi_mana` part without using the `xlsxwriter` module?

Note:

a) The 3 dictionaries are created when extracting the data from a input file, the keys and values are not defined by myself, hence I do not know the order of the keys and values in the dictionaries.

b) I wish to write into a .txt or .csv file which will be opened in Excel with tab as the delimiter.

c) I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: What are your feelings about using  the `csv` module? It can certainly help with delimitation (it can be told to use `\t` as a delimiter between columns)

Comment: @Delioth Yes I am happy to use any module as long as I do not need to download it as I have no permission to do so. However, my problem is I do not know how to print out the data in a table like I mentioned above.

Comment: May I know what are the reasons that I got down-voted?

Comment: For one, `csv` is in the standard library, so you have it already. My guesses as for your downvotes: You don't seem to have tried anything- post what you've tried (with a minimal example of code). Also, most of the question is asking a module to use, which isn't suitable for stackoverflow's Q/A model (it's opinion-based)

Comment: @Delioth Alright I have added my code and will try to look at `csv` module.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to produce your exact desired output, but I got something that will work in Excel.

Your three dictionaries each contain information about an object (or character) so I created a character class rather than use your dictionaries.

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, name, skill, magic, skill_list):
        """
        Initialize the character.  Skill and magic are boolean.
        Skill list is a list of skill tuples. A skill tuple has
        the format: (skill, value, mana)
        """

        self.name = name
        self.skill = skill
        self.magic = magic
        self.skills = {s[0]: (s[1], s[2]) for s in skill_list}
```

Then create each character:

```
ben_skills = [
    ('Strength', 1.10, 'wo_mana'),
    ('Speed', 1.50, 'wo_mana'),
    ('Int', 1.20, 'wi_mana')
]
tom_skills = [
    ('Agility', 1.60, 'wo_mana'),
    ('Int', 1.40, 'wi_mana')
]
characters = [
    Character('Ben', True, False, ben_skills),
    Character('Tom', True, True, tom_skills)
]
```

And write them to a CSV file (Excel knows how to read these):

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Name,Skill,Magic,wo_mana,wi_mana\n')

    for c in characters:
        wo_mana = []
        wi_mana = []

        for k, s in c.skills.items():
            if s[1] == 'wo_mana':
                wo_mana.append('{} = {}'.format(k, s[0]))
            elif s[1] == 'wi_mana':
                wi_mana.append('{} = {}'.format(k, s[0]))

        f.write('{},{},{},{},{}\n'.format(
            c.name,
            str(c.skill),
            str(c.magic),
            '; '.join(wo_mana),
            '; '.join(wi_mana)
        ))
```

There is probably a better way to do this.  Using `import csv` could have improvements (read about CSV [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)).

Hope this helps!

Comment: The 3 dictionaries are created when extracting the data from a input file, hence I could not define the keys and values myself (or create a character class). Sorry for not providing enough information.